# How to show parent and child in view with will paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm having trouble showing my view correctly. I have this as my code right now:

```
<% for store in @stores %>
  <% store.name %>
    <% @stores.products.each do |p| %>
     <% p.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

def index
 @stores = Store.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
end
```

But end up with the error:

```
undefined method `products'
```

I'm trying to show a store and then all of its products, repeating this on the same page as much as possible e.g:

```
Store1
 Product1
 Product2

Store2
 Product1
 Product2
 Product3
 Product4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that be `store.products` inside the loop, where you're accessing `store`?

```
<% for store in @stores %>
  <%= store.name %>
    <% store.products.each do |p| %>
     <%= p.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And `=` is added to the output lines. `<%=`

Comment: Then why does it give me the error: `undefined local variable or method stores` when I do this? Maybe because its in a different controller then the `StoresController`?

Comment: @Railslearner If this is in a from a different controller, `@stores` has not been defined in the method you're currently calling to render this view.

Comment: @Railslearner wait, do you mean you changed `@stores` to `stores` and now you get the error?  Notice that my example above is `store.products.each`, not plural `stores.product.each`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `<% @stores.products.each do |p| %>` I think you mean `<% store.products.each do |p| %>`:

Also, do you not mean to have `<%=` on the `store.name` and `p.name` lines?

```
<% for store in @stores %>
  <%= store.name %>
    <% store.products.each do |p| %>
      <%= p.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```